# hexadecimal bit wise and operation

Tags: perl

I am fresher in writing scripts so need some help.

so the issue is in one of my script i am doing a bitwise AND operation but i am getting wrong data.

elaborating on this:

```
$value have a hex value 0xffffffc0.
```

And i have done some grepping and i have hex value stored in $pattern.

so i need to do and operation of $value & $pattern but getting wrong data, because whatever the $value i am passing its getting converted into decimal value.

```
$value = hex '0xffffffc0' ;
print $value;
$pattern = 0x35040 ; ####this value will be from the grepping#### 
$pattern1 = $pattern & 0xfffffffc;

print "$pattern1\n";
```

i am seeing O/P: 35008

Comment: You aren't "passing" `$value` to anything. I can't reproduce the issue: `perl -le 'my $pattern = 0x35040; my $pattern1 = $pattern & 0xfffffffc; print $pattern1'` (correctly) gives (decimal) `217152` and `perl -le 'my $pattern = 0x35040; my $pattern1 = $pattern & 0xfffffffc; printf "%#x\n", $pattern1'` (correctly) gives `0x35040`. Regardless this appears to be a pure perl programming question so would be better asked on [so]

Comment: The printf tells me the hexadecimal value but the value is further used in the code for some calculation. Will it be correct

Answer (score 0):

You can specify hexadecimal numbers like `$hex_number = 0xaf56`, `hex` converts a string having hexadecimal text into the equivalent number, i.e. `$hex_number == hex 'af56'`. Numbers are represented in binary inside a computer and they will behave properly with any bit-wise operation you do on them.

It is only when you print a number that you need to be careful about how you want it formatted. By default numbers are printed in decimal, you can print in hexadecimal using the `%x` format specifier with `printf`.